# Eclipse CDT Build Settings lost with restart

Tags: java, eclipse, project, flags, eclipse-cdt

I programmatically create a Eclipse CDT project and set some extra options in Cygwin C Compiler's Miscellaneous flags(Buld -> Settings-> Tool Settings).

My problem is when I restart eclipse I couldn't see the extra values I enetered programmatically in to the flags. It always resets to the default values.

What is the problem with this approach?

Comment: Created a CDT project as following. CCorePlugin.getDefault().createCProject(description,   newProjectHandle, 
                 new NullProgressMonitor(), 
                 ManagedBuilderCorePlugin.MANAGED_MAKE_PROJECT_ID);

Comment: cCompilers = toolChain.getToolsBySuperClassId("cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.c.compiler.cygwin.exe.debug");                                                   for (int j = 0; j < cCompilers.length; j++) {
 if (cCompilers[j].getName() == "Cygwin C Compiler") {
    cCompiler = cCompilers[j];cCompiler.getOptionById("gnu.c.compiler.option.misc.other").setValue(newValue);